# Thinking_sphinx Search method doesn't work when I include ransack gem in my Gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thinking-sphinx, ransack

I included thinking_sphinx gem in my project.

`Article.search "Bla-bla-bla"` works fine.

But when I include ransack gem in my Gemfile I get the error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `with_indifferent_access' for "Bla-bla-bla":String from /Users/ashvalev/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/ransack-0.7.2/lib/ransack/search.rb:21:in `initialize'
```

It is because ransack gem also uses name "search" for its searching method.

What can I do to make these gems work together?

Comment: Was this ever resolved by you?  I just ran into exactly the same issue with Rails 4 project.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to call ThinkingSphinx.search instead of the specific model's #search method.

Instead of

```
Article.search "Bla-bla-blah"
```

Use the system-wide search call, but constrain to the class...

```
ThinkingSphinx.search "Bla-Bla-Blah", classes: [Article]
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to list ransack before thinking-sphinx in your Gemfile - the load order matters.

Though I would certainly recommend just using one of the two when it comes to searches.